# Strong Validation in WPF

Tags: wpf, validation, data-binding

I have a databound TextBox in my application like so: (The type of `Height` is `decimal?`)

```xml
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Height, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                            ValidatesOnExceptions=True, 
                            Converter={StaticResource NullConverter}}" />
```

```cs
    public class NullableConverter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert(object o, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            return o;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object o, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            if (o as string == null || (o as string).Trim() == string.Empty)
                return null;
            return o;
        }
    }
```

Configured this way, any non-empty strings which cannot be converted to decimal result in a validation error which will immediately highlight the textbox. However, the TextBox can still lose focus and remain in an invalid state. What I would like to do is either:

1. Not allow the TextBox to lose focus until it contains a valid value.
2. Revert the value in the TextBox to the last valid value.

What is the best way to do this?

**Update:**

I've found a way to do #2. I don't love it, but it works:

```
private void TextBox_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var box = sender as TextBox;
    var binding = box.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    if (binding.HasError)
        binding.UpdateTarget();
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this better? (Or do #1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the keyboard focus to stay on the `TextBox` by handling the `PreviewLostKeyBoardFocus` event like this:

```xml
     <TextBox PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus" />
```

```cs
     private void TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e) {
         e.Handled = true;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you'll want to handle two events:

GotFocus: Will trigger when the textbox gains focus. You can store the initial value of the box.

LostFocus: Will trigger when the textbox loses focus. At this point you can do your validation and decide if you want to roll back or not.